# Update using modal and php

Tags: php, get, crud

I'm doing a CRUD operation using php and bootstrap only. I'm currently stuck at update because I cant seem to send the `$_GET['updateid']` to my modal.

This is my href's, the **delete** `href` is working but the **update** is not.

```
<a href="#myModal?updateid=<?php echo $row['sched_id'];?>" data-toggle="modal"  
              class="btn btn-warning" data-target="#myModal">Update</a>
<a href="home.php?deleteid=<?php echo $row['sched_id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

This php should take the `updateid` from the `href` and pass it to the updateStud() function

```
if(isset($_GET['updateid'])){
  $mupdate_id = $_GET['updateid'];

  if(isset($_POST['modal-submit'])){

    $msubj = $_POST['modalsubject'];
    $msect = $_POST['modalsection'];
    $mday = implode("", $_POST['modalday']);
    $mstrTime = $_POST['modalstarttime'];
    $mendTime = $_POST['modalendtime'];

    $auth_user->updateSchedule($msubj,$msect,$mday,$mstrTime,$mendTime,$mupdate_id);
    $schedRow = $auth_user->readSchedule();
  }
}
```

this is my function update that takes all the data and executes the query

```
public function updateSchedule($msubj,$msect,$mday,$mstrTime,$mendTime,$mupdate_id){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE `schedule`   
            SET `subject_db` = :msubj,
            `section_db` = :msect,
            `sched_day` = :mday,
            `start_time` = :mstrTime,
             `end_time` = :mendTime
            WHERE `sched_id` = :mupdate_id ");

        $stmt->bindparam(":msubj", $msubj);
        $stmt->bindparam(":msect", $msect);
        $stmt->bindparam(":mday", $mday);
        $stmt->bindparam(":mstrTime", $mstrTime);
        $stmt->bindparam(":mendTime", $mendTime);
        $stmt->bindparam(":mupdate_id", $mupdate_id);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are avoiding Javascript?  Unfortunately I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.  Whereas the delete link is a server request, the modal link is a client request that will not invoke your "if(isset($_GET['updateid'])){" because the page is not actually being submitted.

Comment: I think that's wrong you're trying to do there. You're trying to set the `updateid` URL `GET` parameter to the modal anchor trigger link. That's not how it works. If you want to pass the `updateid` as a `GET` parameter, then you add it at the end of your form action attribute. Can you edit your question and update with the full html code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to using this script to your modal.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-target" data-id="<?= $idyouwant ?>">Change</a>
```

You can fill your modal with html that you want via ajax/jquery like this javascript

```
$('#modal-target').on('show.bs.modal', function(ev){
    var modal = $(this);
    var link = $(ev.relatedTarget);
    var id = link.data('id');
    modal.find('.modal-body').load('yourserver/?param=' + id); // will load modal body that you want
}
```

then you can configure your script as well as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to update the data using modal and display the response inside the modal, you do not need to add the `#myModal` to the link. You should use it like this

```
"?updateid=<?php echo $row['sched_id'];?>"
```

instead of

```
"#myModal?updateid=<?php echo $row['sched_id'];?>"
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Are you sure you do not need to include home.php in the update url like in delete?

Comment: If you only want to update the data using bootstrap modal and display the result inside the model, you do not need to add `#myModal` to the link. Just remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same modal with different activating links throughout your page you'll have to populate through javascript/jquery. The modal doesn't accept parameters from the target string unless you change the boostrap.js function directly (I don't recommended messing with vendor js files).  You can do an inline onclick method if you can't add your own script to the page for whatever reason.

JQuery:

`<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning" data-target="#myModal" onclick="$('#updateid').val('<?= $row['sched_id'] =?>')">Update</a>`

You'll need a hidden input on your form 
`<input type='hidden' id='updateid' name='updateid'/>` which will then pass a parameter when you submit your form with the GET method.

If you're using this as the only link to your modal you can echo out your field in the modal `<input type='hidden' name='updateid' value='<?= $row['sched_id']?>'/>`

Answer (score -1):

@tjfo made an observation in the comments of your original question, and is correct. The browser is not calling your script, because of the "#Modal?..." link.  When you tell the browser to load a new "#" location on the same page, the browser does not communicate with the server to get a new  instance of the page.

If you want to make this work without using javascript to send messages to the server, you can create unique access points that each have their own URL on the server. That would force the browser to reload the page on each call, and it would send a request to the server to complete the action.

A similar approach would be to change the web server settings so that calls to new URLs are all redirected to your main script (index.php, for example).

Neither of these approaches is truly recommended, because your script uses $_POST references, and the browser does not send POST data when loading a new page.

The cleanest method would be to use your bootstrap button to call a javascript function with the necessary id. Use javascript to create a url. Package ALL your data in the POST data (See note after paragraph). Use javascript to call the server (read up on AJAX) with your POST data, and then handle the response appropriately.

(Note: it does not make sense to send GET data and POST data on the same request --- note, if you insist on having the option to send the id using GET parameters from time to time, you can use the $_REQUEST variable to access both the $_POST and $_GET data simultaneously).

I'm happy to work through this with you in the comment section. Post more of your code, and more people can provide additional assistance.